# Create a testing Framework

Tags: java, bdd, functional-testing

I am currently trying to develop a testing Framework and currently have all GUI tested using selenium web driver. Now I wish to use my frame work to do functional testing. This would (1)include a do some work on the GUI (2) run test scripts from the command line using java jsch.

So I have a a base class that includes common methods for all selenium classes I have a class which creates objects for every page. I then run my tests from a test class based on each page class. Now I wish to add a jsch class which will run my scripts. I'm a little confused how to do this and I think this is to do with my limited knowledge of Java. So I will try to explain it like this

class A is my base class

class B is object class which inherits A

class C is my test class that initialises the elements and runs my test

(new)class D is my jsch class that runs my command line scripts.

What is the best way to include class D in my test class C. Should I just create a new object in my test class. Or is there a better more elegant method using inheritance polymorphism etc.

Comment: You also can starting using one of available frameworks for selenium those have proven and efficient implementation so you can concentrate on your AUT specific implementation. On of the framework i can suggest is [QMetry Automation Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148345/selenium-java-browser-session-reuse/40400187#40400187). Here you can [find documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/). It support provides Behavior driven authoring by QAF-BDD and [cucumer gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) (for cucumber users)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider create D in C with new D(); or use dependency injection and inject D in the constructor of C.

I would not use polymorphism for introducing logic in a class.

Personally I find it a lot easier to understand when I use composition instead of polymorphism (inheritance).